# Real analysis - applying Darboux's theorem

Tags: real-analysis

I've been given this exercise: Given $g:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, and $0\leq g'(x)\leq 1$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, prove that there exists some point $0\leq c\leq 1$ such that $g'(c)=3c^2$

Now, here's what I tried:

I want to apply Darboux's theorem, so I want to find a suitable $c$ such that $g'(0)\leq 3c^2\leq g'(1)$ (assuming without loss of generality that $g'(0)\leq g'(1)$).

Solving for $c$ I get $\sqrt{\frac{g'(0)}{3}}\leq c\leq \sqrt{\frac{g'(1)}{3}}$.

Now applying Darboux's theorem, since $g'(0)\leq 3c^2\leq g'(1)$, there exists some $d\in(0,1)$ such that $g'(d) = 3c^2$.

And this is where I got stuck. How can I guarantee that $d = c$?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $h(x)=g'(x)-3x^2$.

As $h(x)=(g(x)-x^3)'$ it satisfies Darboux's Theorem.

But $h(0)=g'(0)\geq0$ and $h(1)=g'(1)-3<0$, so there exists some $c\in(0,1)$ where $h(c)=0$, that is, $g'(c)=3c^2$.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail why $h$ satifies Darboux's theorem's conditions?

Comment: $h$ is the derivative of a function, that is the only condition of Darboux's Theorem.

Comment: Ah I see. I think it is more clear to me to take $h(x) = g(x) + x^3$, and then take the derivative of it. But anyways your answer helped me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: One more question. Doesn't Darboux's theorem talk about all values between $h(0)$ and $h(1)$? Can I really say that there exists a $c$ such that $h(c)=0$? Because $h(0)$ might be exactly $0$.

Comment: If $h(0)=0$ we directly have $g'(0)=0=3\cdot 0^2$.

Comment: I see. That settles it then. Thanks!

Comment: @JulioPuerta: I think you applied the theorem incorrectly. You said $h$ satisfied Darboux theorem. This statement is not verified yet. In fact it is not clear if $h$ is differentiable since your $h(x) = g'(x) - 3x^2$ and $h'(x) = g''(x) - 6x$. But you don't have any info about $g''$ as whether $g''$ is even defined or not. It seems to me you applied the IVT to $h$ and not $h'$ in the Darboux sense.

Comment: @WangYeFei No, the theorem is perfectly applied. We cannot apply IVT to $h$ as we don't know if it is continuous. When one says a function satisfies Darboux's Theorem it means the function has the Darboux property, that is, it takes all intermediate values, it does **not** mean its derivative has the Darboux property.

Comment: @JulioPuerta: Ah you are right for the math, but your $h(x)$ should be $h(x) = g(x) -x^3$ and not the one you have above that $h(x) = (g(x) - x^3)'$. Check out Wikipedia on how it states the Darboux property about a function $f$.

Comment: @WangYeFei  No, $h(x)$ is well defined. I believe you are the one who should check your theorems.